# vector function and scalar function?

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

If we have $\lim_{{\bf x}\to {\bf 0}} f({\bf x})=L$, where ${\bf x}$ is a vector
and we know that ${\bf x}=(x_{1},\dots , x_{n})$
can we instead write that $\lim_{{\bf x}\to {\bf 0}} f(x_{1},\dots ,x_{n})=L$?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly following the definition of $f$, one can note that $f$ is a function of one variable (which is $n$-dimensional vector), therefore you cannot write $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, since $f$ would be a function of $n$ variables (which are $1$-dimensional vectors, i. e. numbers) in that case.

However, many would agree that you can write in both ways, especially if you use the notation ${\bf x} = (x_1, \dots ,x_n)$ consistently.

Comment: I am working on a problem which asks us to prove that if and only if every component of the vector x approaches to 0 then these two limits are equal. So I am confused that how can we use epsilon and delta definition to prove it

Comment: @user108701 Which two limits? Your question is only about notation and I think that "both limits" from the question are only one limit, written in two different ways.